# How to open/load a password protected Excel File in Python on Ubuntu OS

Tags: excel, python-3.x, security, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to open an excel file which is password protected. I could find a few solutions but they work on Windows OS only. I am looking for a solution for Linux based OS. Specifically for Ubuntu 16.04.

If someone could please help me with a python code that can help me solve my problem.

TIA

Answer (score -1):

You can try using the unoconv command.
https://linux.die.net/man/1/unoconv

```
apt-get install unoconv
```

To open the password protected file use the below command:

```
unoconv -p p4ssw0rd -f csv  protectedFile.xls
```

and then parse the csv file. Or export to another xls if you need the formatting